# Query to compare Role permissions

Tags: sql, db2, grouping

I have the following tables (simplified format):

Element table

```
| elementId   int         |
| elementDesc VARCHAR(100)|
```

Role table

```
| roleId int            |
| roleName VARCHAR(100) |
```

ElementRole table

```
| elementId  int     |
| roleId int         |
| permission CHAR(1) |
```

Data examples:

Element

```
[1, 'Save'] ,  [2, 'Sale'],  [3, 'Search']
```

Role Table

```
[1, 'Admin'] , [2, 'User'] , [3, 'View Only']
```

RoleElement

```
[1,1,'A'] ,    [2,1,'A'],    [3,1,'A'],     [1, 2, 'A'],   [3,2,'A']
```

As you can see role 1 Admin, has permissions in RoleElement table for all the elements, while User role has only permissions for 2 elements out of 3 and view only role has no permission records at all.

My requirements is to return a result to compare all the roles vs elements, as follow:

```
Element, Admin, User, View Only
-------------------------------------
1    ,   A      ,  A   ,          
2    ,   A      ,      ,   
3    ,   A      ,  A   ,
```

So for each element, they want to see the permissions per role.
If there are no permissions records between the role and the element, they still want to see it blank. (like in the case of view only role)
The purpose is to be able to compare all the permissions between the roles.

I tried so many ways to group the tables using left joins or inner table, but I could not figure out how to get the roles in columns especially when there are no records in RoleElement Table.
There are many roles and elements, it will be hard to run for each and copy/paste into a spreadsheet.

The database is DB2 but if the solution is not in DB2 sql, it will still be ok. I can try to find the equivalent to it in DB2.

Comment: To pivot with a variable number of columns you can use Dynamic SQL to assemble a query on the fly, and then just run it.

Answer (score 0):

This statement would do the job

```
SELECT ELEMENTID
     , max(CASE WHEN roleid = 1 THEN permission end) AS ADMIN
     , max(CASE WHEN roleid = 2 THEN permission end) AS USER
     , max(CASE WHEN roleid = 3 THEN permission end) AS ViewOnly
  FROM elementrole  
 GROUP BY ELEMENTID
```

This is to give you an idea - it may need adjustment if for your (more complex) real example.